# Colors.xml: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: java, android

Yesterday, after few days I’ve installed the latest Android Studio, I created a new module in my project and could not run it, getting a message in event log - "Error: Content is not allowed in trailing section." This message was concerning the colors.xml file, which has just a few lines inside:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">BasicViews</string>
</resources>
```

But I think there is nothing to fix here.

Here there's the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Why would you put string resource into color?

Comment: Move <string name="app_name">BasicViews</string> to string.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the contents of colors.xml namely your string items to values >> strings.xml